# Graph getting messed up when user resizes page

Tags: chart.js

I've finished making my graph and have moved onto trying to put it into a `<article>` tag the thing is when I resize my page it gets messed up and stops fitting inside of the tag, is there anyways to fix this?

**Screenshots:**

[image: What it should look like]
[image: What it actually looks like when resizing]

**Code:**

```html
<article>
   <canvas id="myChart" style="width:676px;height:300px;"></canvas>
   <!-- if there is a way It would be cool for it just to fill to the article -->
</article>
```

```js
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: {.....},
    options: {...}
```

```css
article {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    background: var(--page-content-blockColor);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
}
```

**What I've Tried:**

```
responsive:true,
maintainAspectRatio: false
```

Comment: From the docs "<canvas height="40vh" width="80vw">: invalid values, the canvas doesn't resize". Follow this docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html + And this example: https://codepen.io/chartjs/pen/YVWZbz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks User: Ezra Siton,

Changing to using VH and VW seemed to work for me!

:)

(posting this so i can close the question)